# access same-name members when class C : A : B

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, inheritance

I made a bad mistake in trying to design a framework where one class would inherit two others; forgetting that C# doesn't have multiple inheritance. Because of this error, I made a workaround.

> A : B
>   Both : A //Now has all members of both A and B, unless they're hidden

If A and B both have a member by the same name, can I access the member of B (hidden by A) without changing the framework, and if so, how?

**Edit**: Classes A and B are not meant to be instantiated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach you could take is to extract the method into a pair of interfaces and use explicit interface implementations in classes A, B.

```
interface IA {
    void Method();
}

interface IB {
    void Method();
}

abstract class B : IB {
    void IB.Method() { ... }
}

abstract class A : B, IA {
    void IA.Method() { ... }
}

class Both : A { ... }
```

You must then cast to the interface to access the methods, and attempting to call Method without the cast results in a compile time error.

```
Both x = new Both();
((IA)x).Method();
((IB)x).Method();

x.Method() //invalid call
```

Comment: Mark, excellent answer. Note you can create a 'default' implementation too, that calls either `IA` or `IB`.

Answer (score 2):

```
C c = new C();
c.Member("This is C's version, if there is one; otherwise it's A's");
((A)c).Member("This is A's version");
((B)c).Member("This is B's version");
```

Comment: I updated my question to include important information that would make your answer irrelevant. Sorry; I didn't think about that.

Comment: Updated: this should work - you can still cast to a class without instantiating it.